# Custom Attribute redirect causes "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My MVC 3 webapp has different parts which require to check whether the user is a user or an admin, they all get access to the same pages, except some pages have controllers (buttons and textboxes) that only admins can see. I do that check by putting the user's access level into my viewmodel and doing a check:

```
@if (Model.UserAccess != "Viewer")
{
    [do something]
}
```

I check in my action what access the logged in user has. If the session were to timeout I redirect them to the logon page.

My action is called from a Project page view and loaded as a partial:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("CategoryList", "Home", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId });}
```

And my Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult CategoryList(int categoryid = 0)
{
    var useraccess = GetUseraccess();

    [blablabla stuff done here]

    var model = new CategoryViewModel()
    {
        CategoryList = categorylist
        UserAccess = useraccess
    };

    return PartialView(model);
}

public string GetUseraccess()
{
    var useraccess = "viewer"; //default

    var check = SessionCheck();
    if (check == "expired")
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Session expired. Please login again.");

        Response.Redirect("/Account/LogOn");
    }
    else if (check == "admin")
    {
        useraccess = "admin";
    }

    return useraccess;
}

public string SessionCheck()
{
    if (Session["UserAccess"] == null)
    {
        return "expired";
    }
    else if ((string)Session["UserAccess"] == "admin")
    {
        return "admin";
    }
    else // viewer
    {
        return "viewer";
    }
}
```

Now that works fine. However I've been trying to implement a custom attribute that would check the session's expiration before the controller is fired:

```
public class CheckUserAccessSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var useraccess = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserAccess"];
        if ((string)useraccess == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" }));
        }
    }
}

[CheckUserAccessSession]
public PartialViewResult CategoryList(int categoryid = 0)
{
    [same stuff as above here]
}
```

I get the error

`Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.`

I understand why the error happens. But I haven't found how to go around it. Similarly I'd like to send to my action some data from another custom attribute but that also isn't working because of the RedirectToRouteResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here that is you're returning a PartialViewResult on that action method, and by definition the output of that action method is going to be only a portion of the full request served by IIS. You should be doing permissions checking on the action method that serves the full view in which the partial view is incorporated.

Technically when you're calling Response.Redirect in your initial implementation you're breaking far away from the ASP.NET MVC design conventions; even though it works, it's bad design.

Comment: I thought about that, but the main rarely gets reloaded. The partials inside however do quite often. So I was doing that so that if a user does time out and come back the check has to be done on the partials since the main view won't get triggered again? How else could I do that? I would like to have the Response.Redirect changed to a RedirectToRouteResult but it's the same issue that a child action can't redirect.

Comment: Lan, in that case what I would do is return a different partial view that instructs the user to login (you can specify views by name when you're returning them); without re-architecting your application, that's one simple thing you could try.

Comment: Your second answer is the one I support :D

Comment: Thanks for the help btw! I removed my second answer as returning a value and having my partial action redirecttoaction gave me the same error anyway :/ As for the view I can send back something like `filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Log" };` the problem is that the partial gets loaded in place of the action's partialview which causes a website within a website... :(  And asking the user to log out and log back in isn't really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code. It will work.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            PartialViewResult result = new PartialViewResult();
            result.ViewName = "noaccess";


            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
```